# Help logging SMB network share activity

Tags: networking, logs, samba

For the purpose of this question, I have a server called `server1` hosting the **samba** network share `share1` on my local network. `User1` can access this share with read and write permissions.

I'm looking to be able to log every bit of activity in a simple, plain basic format that occurs in the share.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 accessed share1 from device1
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 opened folder1
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 deleted file 'filename'
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 created folder 'folder2'
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 created file 'file1'
```

And so on.

In a really simple to read format that logs all types of activity such as the creation and deletion of files and folders, accessing files and folders, renaming, deleting, moving, permission changes, etc (maybe even execution of a file)

**All help appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

here is what I do, this is the best I've been able to cobble together.
Web search on *samba vfs extd_audit* for more detail

Adjust log level from 0 to a higher number to suit your needs

`/etc/samba/smb.conf` on the samba server

```
 [global]
    workgroup = SAMBA
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    load printers = no
    disable spoolss = yes

    log level = 0 vfs:10

    log file = /var/log/samba/sambavfs.log
    # no log rotation
    max log size = 0

    smb encrypt = required
    client min protocol = SMB3
    client max protocol = SMB3
   #  client ipc signing = mandatory
    client signing = mandatory
    server signing = mandatory
    obey pam restrictions = yes

[data]
    comment = data
    inherit acls = Yes
    read only = No
    path = /data
    directory mask = 770
    create mask = 660
    vfs objects = extd_audit
```